TEXmate - Hide the text used to generate the diagram?
I'm trying to make a doocument that just shows a bunch of positions, no commentary or text/notation. I'm using the Texmate package. Here is the code I have right now:
\begin{document}
|e4 e5 Nc3 Nc6\toD*|
\nodiagrammove
\makediagrams
\end{document}

skak has the \hidemoves function, which did exactly what I wanted, but I struggled getting skak to line up many diagrams in a position that looks aestheic.
Is there some way to do hide the text of the line for the diagram in TEXmate? This is what is currently produced. I want "1.e4 e5 2.Nc3 Nc6" to not be printed. I know there's the transparent/phantom technique one can use within LaTeX, but I don't want that text to take up space on the page either.


Welcome to TeX.SE!

With xskak + chessboard you can use \hidemoves:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\setchessboard{tinyboard,showmover=false}
\begin{document}
Test board
\newchessgame
\hidemoves{1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6}
\chessboard
\hidemoves{3. Nf3 Nf6}
\chessboard

\end{document}



You can do that with Lua(La)TeX, luamplib and mpchess:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{
    input mpchess;
    set_backboard_width(3cm);
    string pgnstr;
    pgnstr := "1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Nf3 Nf6";
    beginfig(0);
    build_chessboards_from_pgn(pgnstr);
    init_backboard;
    draw backboard;
}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}
    Test board
\begin{mplibcode}
    draw chessboard_step(4);
\end{mplibcode}
\begin{mplibcode}
    draw chessboard_step(6);
\end{mplibcode}
    
\end{document}


